# Building APK with Gluon Client Plugin - org/apache/log4j/Priority ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, log4j, gluon-mobile, javafx-11

This issue occurs when I run **mvn client:build -P android** command.

Following is the part of the log file (target/client/log/**process-compile-1623118972116.log**).

```
[com.fivedtech.parent.app.main:9813]   (features):   8,766.68 ms,  3.00 GB
[com.fivedtech.parent.app.main:9813]     analysis: 178,649.72 ms,  3.00 GB
[com.fivedtech.parent.app.main:9813]     universe:   5,355.83 ms,  3.02 GB
Fatal error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:603)
    ool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 17 more
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:488)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:370)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:529)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:119)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:561)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
    at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.CompilerToVM.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.hotspot.HotSpotResolvedObjectTypeImpl.getDeclaredMethods(HotSpotResolvedObjectTypeImpl.java:987)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNIAccessibleMethod.anyMatchIgnoreReturnType(JNIAccessibleMethod.java:139)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNIAccessibleMember.findHidingSubclasses(JNIAccessibleMember.java:103)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNIAccessibleMember.setHidingSubclasses(JNIAccessibleMember.java:83)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNIAccessibleMethod.finishBeforeCompilation(JNIAccessibleMethod.java:135)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNIAccessFeature.beforeCompilation(JNIAccessFeature.java:350)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$doRun$2(NativeImageGenerator.java:619)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:619)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:476)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinP
```

Here's the [full log file](https://pastebin.com/vvrwTxQU).

I've tried adding '**log4j-core**' and '**log4j-api**' libraries to classpath. But still this issue occurs.

Following is the pom.xml,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.fivedtech</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>School Parent Application</name>
  <description>School Parent Application Project</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <import-control-file>import-control.xml</import-control-file>

    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
    <attach.version>4.0.11</attach.version>
    <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
    <client.maven.plugin.version>0.1.41</client.maven.plugin.version>

    <school.dto.version>1.0.51-SNAPSHOT</school.dto.version>
    <main.class>com.fivedtech.parent.app.Main</main.class>
  </properties>

  <organization>
    <name>FiveDTech, Inc.</name>
    <url>http://www.fivedtech.com</url>
  </organization>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fivedtech</groupId>
      <artifactId>comsat-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.airhacks</groupId>
      <artifactId>afterburner.fx</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfxtras-controls</artifactId>
      <version>9.0-r1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fivedtech</groupId>
      <artifactId>school-dto</artifactId>
      <version>${school.dto.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- ATTACH PLUGINS ARE DECLARED HERE -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>CB Parents</finalName>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.css</include>
          <include>**/*.fxml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <propertyExpansion>import-control-file=${import-control-file}</propertyExpansion>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
              <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${client.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <target>${client.target}</target>
          <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
          <attachList>
            <list>storage</list>
            <list>lifecycle</list>
            <list>dialer</list>
            <list>browser</list>
            <list>push-notifications</list>
            <list>runtime-args</list>
            <list>util</list>
          </attachList>
          <bundlesList>
            <list>application</list>
          </bundlesList>
          <reflectionList>
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.SchoolPresenter</list>
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.SchoolService</list>
              <!-- Splash -->
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.splash.SplashPresenter</list>
              <!-- Login -->
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.login.LoginPresenter</list>
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.login.LoginService</list>
              <!-- Progress -->
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.progress.ProgressPresenter</list>
              <list>com.fivedtech.parent.app.progress.ProgressService</list>

          </reflectionList>
          <nativeImageArgs>
            <nativeImageArg>--allow-incomplete-classpath</nativeImageArg>
          </nativeImageArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>android</id>
      <properties>
        <client.target>android</client.target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>ios</id>
      <properties>
        <client.target>ios</client.target>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And this issue hasn't occurred before.
What is the reason for this issue? And How to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried  `mvn client:runagent` first?

Comment: Yes I **mvn client:runagent**. The app ran normally.

Comment: Make sure that when you run it, you explore all possible scenarios of your app. It generates a list of json files under resources/META-INF, check that the log4j classes are included (especially `org.apache.log4j.Priority`).

Comment: I've found the cause of this issue. Using incorrect **log4j** is the reason. I've replaced **log4j 2.14.1** with **log4j 1.2.17**. This issue hasn't occurred after this change. And both `mvn client:build -P android` and `mvn client:package -P android` completes successfully. By the way, we aren't using log4j in our app. It seems required by some dependencies.

Comment: Great. In case you don't use it, you can try to find which dependency adds it and then add an exclusion to it in your pom.

Comment: Sure. But I've stumbled upon another issue. The generated APK doesn't run in a device. I've checked the logcat statements and the error shown is same as [this github issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/332). Is there any solutions for this issue?

Comment: AWT is not supported (at least for now) on Android, so you shouldn't use it. I commented the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832813/error-running-apk-file-with-gluon-mobile-on-android).

Comment: I've checked my project. None of the classes use `java.awt.*` package. And none of the dependencies seem using AWT. Is there any other places do I need to check?

Comment: The GitHub issue you linked is using `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`. Check on desktop, see if you have a dependency on java.desktop? Or Swing?

Comment: I've throughly checked the app. It does not contain any AWT or swing components. But still this issue occurs.

Comment: Using `Apache HTTP client` is causing this `JNI_OnLoad_awt` issue. When I replaced it with `Okhttp client` this issue did not occur. Is there any additional configurations needed to build native image with apache HTTP client? How to make it work?

Comment: The JNI_OnLoad_awt issue occurs with Java 11's HttpClient too. But it doesn't occur when Okhttp client is used.